# Why Am I Getting Error Using TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc, transactionscope

Everybody!

I am having trouble with TransactionScope. I want my web method to be transactional. If any exception occurs, I want all database changes rolled back. Otherwise, commit. Please see error message below.

> System.ApplicationException: Error in someClass :: Method public
> returnType methodName(parameterType parameter) :
>
> System.ApplicationException: Error in someClass :: Method private
> string someMethod() :
>
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937):
>
> ERROR [08003] [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Connection not open
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open_EnlistTransaction(Transaction
> transaction)
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen.EnlistTransaction(Transaction
> transaction)
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction
> transaction)
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
>
> at someNameSpace.someMethod() in c:\somePath\someClass.cs:line 35

The following is an excerpt of my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 [WebMethod]
 public returnType methodName(parameterType parameter)
 {
     using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
     {
         try
         {
             var someValue = someMethod();
                 :
                 :
                 :

             transactionScope.Complete();

             return response;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return ErrorMessages(ex);
         }
     }
 }

 private string someMethod()
 {
     var commandText = "...some valid SQL expression...";
     var commandType = CommandType.Text;

     try
     {
         using (var odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(DefaultDbConnection.ToString()))
         {
             using (var odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(commandText, odbcConnection))
             {
                 odbcConnection.Open();  // Exception is thrown here!
                 odbcCommand.CommandType = commandType;

                 using (var reader = odbcCommand.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     reader.Read();
                     return reader.GetString(0);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new ApplicationException("Error in someMethod.", ex);
     }
 }
```

Thank-you in advance for your help!

Comment: Presumably you're saying that the same code works fine without the transaction scope, is that right? Ultimately: not all providers support that API, and I would advise against it *anyway*. What is the thing that you're talking to here? (It is very hard to know that with ODBC, since that is a fallback legacy API). Note that you could *try* moving the Open() call above the command construction.

Comment: Hi, Marc!...

Thank-you for your prompt response.

I am so happy that my problem has caught your attention.  I was hoping you would respond.  I have seen many of your responses.  I always find them helpful...

Comment: When I comment-out the "using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())" and the "transactionScope.Complete()" lines, the web method works perfectly, exactly as expected, without errors or warnings. Only when I introduce the TransactionScope, the "odbcConnection.Open()" throws the following exception when the odbcConnection attempts to enlist the transaction:

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937):
ERROR [08003] [Sybase][ODBC Driver]Connection not open

Comment: I have tried the following...

 using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
 using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) // default
 using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))

None of them work.

Comment: I have tried "odbcConnection.Open()" _before_ the "using (var odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(commandText, odbcConnection))". That didn't work either.

Comment: What would you do given my objective and situation?

Comment: You didn't answer the question of what you're connecting to here - which can matter - but as I said: what I would do is stop using transaction scope, and use the regular ADO.NET transaction model

Comment: Hi, Marc...  I am connecting to Sybase...  

Comment: my *hunch* would be that sybase simply doesn't support this API, or it hasn't been correctly implemented; you could *try* moving the `Open()` a line earlier, before the `new OdbcCommand`, but ultimately, my advice remains the same: **don't use `TransactionScope`** - use the regular `BeginTransaction` API instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, not all connection types - and not all platforms - support transaction scope based transactions, and even when they do: they can be unpredictable because of scoping problems when talking to multiple systems, requiring things like DTC.

Instead, I would strongly suggest simply: *don't use transaction scope* (unless you have a very good reason). Instead, prefer the much simpler and more widely supported ADO.NET transaction model:

- use `BeginTransaction` (or the async equivalent) on the connection to (unsurprisingly) begin a transaction
- carry that transaction instance around in the code
- set the transaction property on each command (I've never understood why this would be necessary given that it is implied through the connection, but: it is)
- make sure to commit or abort the transaction at the end, ideally using `try`/`catch`/`finally` so that it happens correctly in both success and failure

Comment: Based on your earlier response, I decided to give up on TransactionScope and do it the "old-fashioned" way...  Using `BeginTransaction` and `try`/`catch`/`finally`...  Effectively what you wrote above.

I am truly grateful for your help...

Thank-you!